# Displaying fractions in text

Tags: text

We are trying to display 3/16" in the text on a wordpress website but are unable to show this in the same format as other fractions like ½ or ¼.  We have a measurement to write into text of 1 3/16" but want this to appear like ½ or ¼.

Thanks

Comment: `<sup>3</sup>⁄<sub>16</sub>` see e.g.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7525977/how-to-write-fraction-value-using-html

Answer (score 2):

We can paste `<sup>3</sup>⁄<sub>16</sub>` into the visual editor

[image]

or write the HTML in the code editor:

```
<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p>Testing <sup>3</sup>⁄<sub>16</sub> fraction</p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->
```

or use the subscript and superscript on the text paragraph selections in the visual editor:

[image]